# Using Trello to track Progress of a task group (A group of tasks)

Tags: trello

I am not sure if a concept of a group task is available in Trello, below is what we are trying

- A number of team member create individual level tasks and push them through backlog, working, done etc.
- A bunch of these tasks form a group task. Let's say team member A is doing task P, Q, R and Q is an important dependency for another task S which is being done by team member B. We do not know how to link dependencies.
- A & B's team lead wants to know what is happening to hist "group task" or a mini project or whatever we call it. It might involve a series of tasks some of which has dependency relationship. Others are in a schedule and sequence.

Question is how to have that group-task or mini-project view?

Comment: In this scenario are all the cards on the same board?

Comment: Yes. One board.

Answer (score 0):

We had this exact use case and created some free Power-Ups that allows you to do that:

[Card Dependencies for Trello](https://screenful.com/card-dependencies-for-trello)

[Epic Cards for Trello](https://screenful.com/epics-for-trello)

These are both free and work across multiple boards.